# get user names in an Active Directory Group via .net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, active-directory

The below code gets me the users in the group but it is returned
`"CN=johnson\,Tom,OU=Users,OU=Main,DC=company,DC=com"`

I want to just return the First and Last name. How can I accomplish this?

```
DirectoryEntry ou = new DirectoryEntry();
DirectorySearcher src = new DirectorySearcher();

src.Filter = ("(&(objectClass=group)(CN=Gname))");
SearchResult res = src.FindOne();
if (res != null)
{
    DirectoryEntry deGroup = new DirectoryEntry(res.Path);
    PropertyCollection pcoll = deGroup.Properties;

    foreach (object obj in deGroup.Properties["member"])
    {
            ListBox1.Items.Add(obj.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: The following isn't really an answer, just a warning: wrap your DirectoryEntry, DirectorySearcher and especially any SearchResultCollections (e.g. from calling [DirectorySearcher.FindAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.findall.aspx)) in a using statement, or a try/finally with a Dispose call. SearchResultCollections cannot be garbage collected. I hunted down a memory leak for days after using an example I found online that didn't Dispose anything. Check MS documentation thoroughly to see what classes involved in searching Active Directory hav

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I prefer using the classes in System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement:

```
PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, "GName");
```

Search through the group.Members property until you have a **Principal** that you want.  Then extract the name like this:

```
foreach (Principal principal in group.Members)
{
   string name = principal.Name;
}
```

Comment: You need to add a reference to **System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement** your project.

Answer (score 2):

Using your code, the **givenName** (*first name*) and **sn** (*last name*) properties should work.

If you use the System.DIrectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace UserPrincipal (as @russell-mcclure suggested), you will find **GivenName** and **Surname** properties also.

AccountManagement is very handy unless you have to traverse a trusted forest and need the global catalog to find the user.

Comment: I bet he also needs to set the PropertiesToLoad http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.propertiestoload.aspx

Comment: In my code hitting a Windows Server 2008 DC under .Net 4.0, I am getting 24 default properties without modifying the PropertiesToLoad in my DirectorySearcher, including givenName and sn...

Comment: I can't seem to use the accountmanagement because it doesn't exist in my directoryservices namespace.

Comment: AccountManagement is in 3.5 and 4.0 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx

Comment: Did you add a reference to your project?

Comment: yeah, I had an issue with adding the reference but it's there now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a PowerShell script that I made to do it without using the AccountManagement classes. It should be easy enough to translate it to C#:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.DirectoryServices");

$groupName = "Grupo Domain";

$directoryEntry = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry;
$directorySearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($directoryEntry, "(&(objectClass=group)(CN=$groupName))");
[void]$directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectSid");
[void]$directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("member");
$result = $directorySearcher.FindOne();

if ($result -eq $null) { return; }

# Try get the group members through the "member" property.
if ($result.Properties["member"].Count -gt 0) {
    foreach ($member in $result.Properties["member"]) {
        $memberSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($directoryEntry, "(&(objectClass=*)(distinguishedName=$member))");
        [void]$memberSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("msDS-PrincipalName");
        $memberResult = $memberSearcher.FindOne();
        if ($memberResult -eq $null) { continue; }
        Write-Output $memberResult.Properties["msDS-PrincipalName"];
    }
    return;
}
if ($result.Properties["objectSid"].Count -gt 0) {
    # The group might be an AD primary group. Try get the members by the PrimaryGroupID.
    $groupSid = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($result.Properties["objectSid"][0], 0);
    # Hacky way to get only the last RID.
    $primaryGroupSid = $groupSid.Value.Replace($groupSid.AccountDomainSid.ToString(), [String]::Empty).TrimStart('-');
    $memberSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($directoryEntry, "(&(objectClass=*)(primaryGroupId=$primaryGroupSid))");
    [void]$memberSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("msDS-PrincipalName");
    $memberResult = $memberSearcher.FindAll();
    if ($memberResult -eq $null) { continue; }
    foreach ($member in $memberResult) {
        Write-Output $member.Properties["msDS-PrincipalName"];
    }
}
```