# Check if user is disabled in active directory

Tags: c#, winforms, active-directory

I am trying to find a way to check if the user is enabled or disabled in the active directory.
I will be checking different domains if the user status is enable or disable. Trying searching around but not able to find any hints how can i accomplish this.

I just need boolean value, for example if user is disabled bool method should return true if not false.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the answer here: 
[get user names in an Active Directory Group via .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901749/get-user-names-in-an-active-directory-group-via-net)

If that fails, use this link information:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx#S8

And last , you can refer here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C#39

I hope it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the userAccountControl bit flag attribute. Its 2nd bit indicates if a user is disabled You can get this by using
 attributes. eg. `(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)` filter will gives you all users list which are disabled.